# Decryption not working when I move an executable from one server to another server

Tags: asp.net, encryption, key, rsa

I am trying to move a solution from one server to a different server.  I copied all the files (from the older server) that I think I need, but when I run the executable on the new server, it fails with:

`Failed to decrypt using provider ‘RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider.`

From what I've been reading, this is because the keys are at the machine level and I need to somehow copy them over to the new machine.  On the old server, I see a folder for `ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto` (with a bunch of sub-folders), and on the new server I do not see such a folder.

Even if I try copying that folder over to the new server, no luck.

**My question is:** If I have a process that runs successfully on one server (where decryption occurs successfully), and I need to move this to a new server, what do I need to move/recreate from an older server to a new server in way of encryption/decryption?

**Note:** this process was developed by someone no longer at the company.  I am not anywhere near the technical level that the person that developed this was, so please keep that in mind with answers.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you also exported and transferred the necessary keys? Please read [Importing and Exporting Protected Configuration RSA Key Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/yxw286t2(v=vs.100))

Comment: I am all set.  I was following the instructions and nothing was working, but I eventually figured it out.